# How to transform Array[(String,List[String])] to Array[(String,String)]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose i am having mapping in following way :

```
[ (1,List[11,12,13]),(2,List[21,22,23]),(3,List[31,32,33]) ]
```

i want to convert/transform this in the form shown below :

```
[ (1,11),(1,12),(1,13),(2,21),(2,22),(2,23),(3,31),(3,32),(3,33)]
```

I am using scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using for comprehension:

```
val input = List((1,List(11,12,13)),(2,List(21,22,23)),(3,List(31,32,33)))

val output = for {
  tuple <- input
  element <- tuple._2
} yield (tuple._1, element)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use flatMap:

```
 val xs = Array( (1,List(11,12,13)),(2,List(21,22,23)),(3,List(31,32,33)) )
 xs.flatMap{ case (s, xs) => xs.map((s,_))}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
array.flatMap { case (key, arr) => arr.map { key -> _ } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like this:

```
for {
   (k,arr) <- arrOfTuple
   el <- arr
 } yield (k -> el)
```